# I would like to know more how present perfect tense and it's derivatives are in passive & active form; thus some concerns are waving over my mind?

Tags: passive-voice, present-tense, perfect-constructions, active-vs-passive

Firstly;

Present perfect- has recreated

> In each of these movies, batman has been recreated as the subconscious mind of American society.

Is this sentence a proper passive and still present perfect, whilst 'been' is used, between 'has' & 'recreated' or is it something else! We know that; we don't have a tense "has been" verb conjugation. And present perfect is only has + recreate + ed...

Grammerly recognized the sentence as passive and was changed to the active, which I have mentioned below...

And of course the active in present perfect tense is;

In each of these movies, they have recreated Batman as the subconscious mind of American society.

Does just the 'they' really make it active!?

Secondly;

Present perfect continuous- they have been recreating

In each of these movies, they have been recreating batman as the subconscious mind of american society.

In here 'they' is used first, so is it still passive sentence 'cause 'been' is used just before recreating or it has changed to active?

Comment: Hello Ali.  I've made a big edit to your question. I've removed the third part. It was about a different topic: forms of the possessive.  There are other question and answers about that but if you feel they don't answer your question, please ask a new question to ask about different forms of the possessive.

Comment: Thanks, it's okay. Just having the terminology you mentioned is enough for me, that said I am able now to advance further into forms of the possessive. Simple, now I know what to do. Thanks again...

Answer (score 1):

The passive voice is "be+past participle".  So "is eaten", "was eaten", "being eaten", "been eaten" are all passive.  But "eat" "ate", "is eating" and "has eaten" are all active.

The passive voice is correctly formed as "Batman has been recreated ... (by them)".  It contains "be+past participle". In your example the agent "by them" is implicit and has been omitted.

In the active voice the subject is explicit, and the "be + past participle" is replaced by the verb.  But since this is a perfective form, both "be" in the passive and the verb in the active are in their past participle form: "They have recreated Batman."

So "they" doesn't make it active.  The lack of "be + past participle" makes it active.

"They have been recreating" is not passive.  It doesn't contain  "be + past participle" Instead it has "be + present participle" and that is the continuous or progressive aspect.  This is not idiomatic in context but it is grammatically okay.

(The last question about possessive form was not relevant to passive and active voice. It should be asked separately.)

Comment: Greetings Sir
Changing "they have been recreating" into passive becomes "has been recreated" or something else. It's what I got from the shared link. It has to do with our topic, more or less.

https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/47767/161487

Comment: "They have been recreating batman" is not idiomatic English.  Anyway formally the transformation to passive would be "Batman has been being recreated (by them)"  But his is **completely unidiomatic**  Do not use.